# Getting error 'There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout ' email channel in MS bot

Tags: botframework

I have published a bot in bot framework and it is working in test window of the bot framework. Then I configured the bot with email channel with office 365 mail. I am getting the error:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this message because you did not use your endpoint for some time. One possibility to try to avoid those `timeout` is to set your published bot to `Always On` on Azure